# Property of functions in several variables, which have polynomial decay

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{C}$ has polynomial decay that is
$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} |x^\alpha f(x)|<\infty, \text{ for any }\alpha\in\mathbb{N}^n  $$
and satisfies
$$\int_0^\infty \left [ \int_{S^{n-1}} |f(rw)|\,d\sigma(w) \right ] g(r) \, dr<\infty, $$
for some positive continuous increasing function $g$ which goes to infinity at infinity.

Is it true that for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$
$$\int_0^\infty \left [ \int_{S^{n-1}} |f(rw)|\,d\sigma(w) \right ] g(r)r^k \, dr<\infty?$$
($\sigma$ is normalised Haar measure of $S^{n-1}$)

Comment: Certainly not. Let $f(rw) = 1/(1+r^2), g(r)\equiv 1.$ The first integral is finite, but the second one, with $k=1,$ is infinite.

Comment: Ur defined $f$ does not have polynomial decay. A function has polynomial decay if it decays faster than reciprocal of any polynomial at infinity